# Заставит ли переопределенный finalize с бесконечным циклом внутри запретить сборщику мусора делать свою работу?

Tags: java, сборщик-мусора

Просто интересно. Заставит ли переопределенный `finalize` с бесконечным циклом внутри запретить сборщику мусора делать свою работу? GC вызывает `finalize` у удаляемого объекта, но ждёт ли он конца выполнения оного?

```
public class ImmortalClass {

    @Override
    protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
        super.finalize();
        while (true) {}
    }
}
```

Тест

```
ImmortalClass a = new ImmortalClass();
a = new ImmortalClass();
```

Comment: Runtime error же будет.

Comment: @Anamnian, нет возможности проверить :) В книге прочитал про `finalize` как `последнее слово перед смертью` и подумал что будет если этот метод взять и сделать вечным. Runtime error? А когда она будет? Можно подробный ответ, пожалуйста.

Comment: Когда программа исчерпает выделенную ей память, очевидно же. Это же по сути бесконечный цикл.

Comment: @Anamnian, понял вас. То есть это все-таки работает) ну а про `OutOfMemoryError` я в курсе.

Comment: А мне казалось, что `super.finalize();` уже уничтожит все, что можно. И цикл никогда вызываться не будет. Я для интереса написал простой код и вызвал GC в ручную, перед этим разыменовав ссылку на объект. Код выполнился мгновенно(правда, возможно я упустил что-то фундаментальное).

Comment: На enSO есть [такой ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18042381/3432401) по этому поводу.

Comment: @Viktorov так ведь чтобы цикл не вызвался (при том что `super.finalize()` был вызван), нужно чтобы в `super.finalize()` было проброшено исключение, или чтобы поток, в котором выполняется этот код, был убит, или чтобы JVM завершила работу.

Comment: @Regent спасибо. Сегодня я узнал чуть чуть нового.

Comment: @Viktorov, читаю книги одни и те же каждые 2-3 месяца и постоянно что-то новое в них вычитываю))